# angularJS: input checked with validation

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs, model

I'm so new in javascript/angularJS, what I have to do is maybe simple, but I don't really know.
I have a checkbox like this :

```
<input id="myInput" type="checkbox" ng-checked="isChecked">
```

And now when i click to perform the value isChecked in my model is updated correctly.
This is the simple part.
Now I have to add a control on the oncheck event. In other words:
before that isChecked is being updated, the value in the model I have to perform a validation and if the validation return false, the value isChecked should not be updated.

Answer (score 2):

You could use `ng-model` and `ng-change` instead of `ng-checked` to perform a function when the checkbox is checked or unchecked:

```
<input id="myInput" type="checkbox" ng-model="myModel.isChecked" ng-change="checkboxChanged()">
```

So that, in your controller, you can handle the event with a function:

```
$scope.myModdel = {
  isChecked = false    //setting initial value for checkbox
};
$scope.checkboxChanged = function() {
  if( some validation error && $scope.myModel.isChecked ) {
    $scope.myModel.isChecked = false;  // uncheck checkbox
  }
}
```

Be sure not to use both `ng-model` and `ng-checked` as described in the docs:

> Note that [ng-checked] should not be used together with ngModel, as this can lead to unexpected behavior.

You can solve your CSS issue by using `ng-class` like so:

```
<input id="myInput" type="checkbox" ng-model="myModel.isChecked" ng-change="checkboxChanged()" ng-class="{'my-class-name': myModel.isChecked }">
```

Comment: I need ng-checked, because I have a css that uses the checked attribute.
I thought to use ng-click and ng-checked :
<input id="myInput" type="checkbox" ng-model="isChecked" ng-checked="checkboxChanged()"> but I think this is an error like use both ng-model and ng-checked.

Comment: Ah, I see. Alternatively you could set up a watch on the `isChecked` scope variable.

Comment: A watcher has it's own issues, though. I still recommend the first answer and using `ng-class` instead of the checked property to solve your styling issue.

Comment: I hear that watcher is much heavy